# Ruby on Rails - Percentage of Time More Than One Call is Active Per Hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RoR application that runs reports on a database of phone calls logged from a help desk.  I've been asked to provide a report that shows the percentage of time, each hour, that more than one technician is on the phone.  The database logs the call id, technician name, and call created at and end time in Y-M-D-H-M-S.  Can anyone suggest a way I can do this?  Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what you want in your report. From whatever I could understand, here is my answer.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to find the number of minutes per hour where *more than one tech at a time* was on a call. For example, if tech one is on the phone from 12:00 to 12:35, and tech two from 12:30 to 1:00, then there is five minutes "overlap" for that hour. Badmoon, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Brandon, you've got it right on.  If I could get it to the level of seconds, that would be ideal but I'd be happy with minutes.  Another way to ask this would be "what percentage of time, grouped by hour, do phone calls overlap?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem at all from what I understand.

```
for each technician  
    look up the entries in the database and get the call created_at and end time  
         for each entry above  
             total_time += end_time.to_seconds - created_at_time.to_seconds
```

Find the difference between the starting time and the end time, you want to track the activity of a technician.
You get the %age of time this way. To get this for each hour, simply convert the time in hours and you are set to go.